# ajax load and conflicting css classes and IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, single-page-application

I am building a simple single page application which contains some divs which I would like to fill with content from my wordpress website.

In order to do that, I am using ajax load and inserting the loaded content into my divs:

```
$('#my_div').load("https://example.com/page/")
```

The problem is that my application uses css from bootstrap which is different from the css from my wordpress website. However, because classes and IDs are identical, the css from the loaded page is replacing the css from my app.

How can I avoid that problem? I don't want to use iframes. Would it be possible to automatically rename every Class and ID name from the imported page so that it does not conflict?

Comment: Do you mean that the content being loaded includes `<style>` elements and/or `<link>` elements which you don't want to load?  Can you remove those from the source if they're not wanted?  I guess it's not entirely clear what specifically is happening or what specifically you're asking.  Can you elaborate on the example?

Comment: As I am loading from a wordpress site, the content includes many styles. Bootstrap is used on that wordpress site and its classes are conflicting with the ones from my app.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use get instead of load and replace the classes inside with [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) if possible. In your case you can do like this:

```
$.get("https://example.com/page/", function(data) {
     // replace classes
     $("#my_div").replaceWith(data);
});
```